# Dymos Single/Multiple shooting and Global Optimizers (Extension possibilities)

Tags: optimization, openmdao

I was wondering if there are attempts to expand dymos to single shooting/multiple shooting problems. Essentially those ones which would solve the dynamic equations in every optimization query call (which would only use the controls as optimization variables). Currently there is the possibility to use solve_segments=True with an implicit numerical integrator (based on the transcription), and this would be similar but possibly also with explicit integrators (As forward Euler in its basic format, or variable step size ones)

This could be beneficial to explore for example global optimization techniques (and combinations) for trajectory optimization /mdo within the same platform and optimal control setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Dymos 1.1.0, and August 2021, time-stepping integration is not included. As you pointed out `solve_segments` provides very similar functionality. We are working on time-stepping, initially with fixed-step Euler integration. We plan to extend it to higher-order RK methods and adaptive-step.  It will allow the same control transcriptions we already have (segment-by-segment interpolation of fully dynamic controls, and phase-wide interpolation of polynomial controls).

We not ready to announce a timeline for when this will be available though. It's still a bit early in development. A safe bet would be about 1 year before the feature is fully baked though.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the answer. This is quite interesting. Do you know more or less when to expect some working versions of it?

Comment: I hesitate to provide a timeline, but the backend of a basic euler implementation is mostly functional now.  We need to tie it to the Dymos transcription interface so that it works as a drop in for the other transcriptions.  I'd expect that to take no more than a few more weeks.  

The higher-order RK is a bit further off and adaptive step will be beyond that, but I can't commit to a timeline yet on those.

Comment: Great to hear. looking forward to it. Do you know if there are already some global optimization capabilities within openmdao? (could be interesting to check with these shooting methods)

Comment: Hi @RobFalck. I saw that there is an ExplicitShooting component already, also reported in the git page, though i get some errors when trying it out. (not supporting path constraints, issues in timeseries when variables are vectors of size>1, etc.) Do you know if its fully functional or if it might be bugs on my side (if so, i will prepare separate questions)?

Comment: ExplicitShooting is still experimental.  You can achieve similar behavior (having the EOM be satisfied at every iteration) by using the `solve_segments` feature in the Radau or GaussLobatto transcriptions.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the solve_segments options, do you know if there is a way to set up the tolerance (or other options) of the solver?

Comment: If you explicitly assign a NewtonSolver to Phase, you can specify whatever options you want.  If not, Dymos will replace the existing "NonlinearRunOnce" solver with a NewtonSolver and specify some settings automatically.
Just set `phase.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=True)` where NewtonSolver will accept whatever other options you want to provide.